# when i want to integration testing with a payment method on my code i got this error. Expected declaration

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, swift4, integration-testing

when i write this code, i faced this message error said it's "Expected declaration" then when i click on the error its drived me to class and message of class "1. In declaration of 'Home'"

NOTE: The Name Of class is "Home"

```
import UIKit

import FirebaseAuth

import goSellSDK

class Home: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }



    @IBAction func barItem(_ sender: Any) {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            // create the alert
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Would you like to SignOut?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

            // add the actions (buttons)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "SignOut", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.destructive, handler: nil))

            // show the alert
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

    let secretKey = SecretKey(sandbox: "YOUR_SANDBOX_SECRET_KEY", production: "YOUR_PRODUCTION_SECRET_KEY") // (format of the key: "sk_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    goSellSDK.secretKey = secretKey
}
```

may this help

[image]

Comment: You probably either have 1 too many closing brackets or 1 too few. Check that your brackets line up.

Comment: can you please check out the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see the problem is in line `goSellSDK.secretKey = secretKey`. You can move this line inside `viewDidLoad` method:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   goSellSDK.secretKey = secretKey
}
```

more about classes and structures you can read in [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html)

---

Looking at an example app provided by goSellSDK-iOS you can see that they are set up secretKey in AppDelegate:

```swift
import class goSellSDK.GoSellSDK //or you can `import goSellSDK`
import class goSellSDK.SecretKey
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
internal class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    internal var window: UIWindow?

    internal func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication) {
        GoSellSDK.secretKey = SecretKey(sandbox: "YOUR_SANDBOX_SECRET_KEY", production: "YOUR_PRODUCTION_SECRET_KEY")
    }
}
```

so I will propose you the same way. This example file you can find here: [AppDelegate.swift](https://github.com/Tap-Payments/goSellSDK-iOS/blob/b9cb4fb1a08738b3c8798a33aa79e090eed744c6/Example/goSellSDKExample/Supporting%20Files/AppDelegate.swift)

---

If you have a problem with setting key in `AppDelegate.swift` I can provide you a new version of `Home` class:

```swift
import UIKit

import FirebaseAuth

import goSellSDK

class Home: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GoSellSDK.secretKey = SecretKey(sandbox: "YOUR_SANDBOX_SECRET_KEY", production: "YOUR_PRODUCTION_SECRET_KEY")
    }



    @IBAction func barItem(_ sender: Any) {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            // create the alert
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Would you like to SignOut?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

            // add the actions (buttons)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "SignOut", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.destructive, handler: nil))

            // show the alert
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
}
```

Notice that you need to use `GoSellSDK`, not `goSellSDK` (it should start with capital `G` letter)

Comment: When i moved it i got this message error "Module 'goSellSDK' has no member named 'secretKey'

Comment: @AhmadBinmana I've updated my answer, let me know if it helps

Comment: I've did what you did in your updated answer and i sow the AppDelegate.swift. Also i imported the all classes on my home.swift file, but its not declare the secretKey, so i got this message error "Use of unresolved identifier 'secretKey'", as well i got this message error "Module 'goSellSDK' has no member named 'secretKey'"

Comment: The key is to use this: `GoSellSDK.secretKey = SecretKey(sandbox: "YOUR_SANDBOX_SECRET_KEY", production: "YOUR_PRODUCTION_SECRET_KEY")`, you have to use `GoSellSDK` not `goSellSDK`

Comment: @AhmadBinmana I've updated my answer to show how you can use it inside  `Home` class

Comment: Thank you so much, now its work with out error, but were should i use this line of code "GoSellSDK.secretKey = secretKye"